# Implementing cloud watch like metric aggregator for real time monitoring of applications

Tags: monitoring, daemon, elastic-stack, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to design something like amazon cloud watch for real time monitoring of applications I own and I run in my own cluster of machines (not AWS cluster).

Basic requirement:

- Ability to publish time and count metric from applications and view them in a Kibana like dashboard.
- Seamless support to publish metrics from applications written in Python, Java and Node.js.

Possible approach that I think will work but I need suggestions on:

- I am thinking of writing a daemon process that will run on all the hosts in my cluster.
- Applications will publish metrics to a file system in a format that this daemon understands. Not sure how this contract will be created for applications written in different languages?
- Daemon will pull this information say every 5 seconds and publish it to the ELK. Not sure how Daemon will distinguish one application from the other. I guess I will have to create some metric registry service that will register applications. I am not sure what all aspects metric registry will be taking care off.

Pointer on this are really appreciated.

Comment: For your basic requirements, are you open to creating a simple module only for pushing data to elastic search ( we use ES with kibana)? If yes, that module will push data to elastic search and you could try to check [CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html), configure the module logs to point to a cloudwatch log groups, and create a [cloudwatch filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) based on the cloudwatch log groups. That will create a metric. Or this isn't desirable in your case?

Comment: Yes I am open to creating a simple module.

Comment: I found some open source project https://prometheus.io/ but not sure if this will be useful

Comment: Haven't used prometheus.io but looks like they have integration to Elasticsearch too. Do you happen to have a read about [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) ? Best you try to at create simple application with pushing data to metric, using prometheus.io or filebeat depending on what you find more easier to use, then decide what suits your needs better.

Answer (score 2):

For your basic requirements.

- Create a simple java(or your choice of language) application that will send data to elastic search, something like **ElasticSearchClientSender**. Check [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest), we use that to send data to our ES. Setup your kibana with the the correct alias. Creating it as a module may not be necessary in your case, as you may just create a snippet and plug it to the application you want its data published to ES.

If you still need the cloudwatch metric for other [monitoring purposes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html), either you could try below options

- [AWS Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-publish-custom-metrics.html) got you covered. **EDIT** they also have one for python, nodejs and others(we mostly use python)
- Or in our case, we have setup each of our module to have its own Cloudwatch Log Groups, so our elastic search sender module has it own log groups. Overview of [Cloudwatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatchLogsConcepts.html). When you have setup the Cloudwatch Log Groups for your module, decide what keyword you want to indicate what you want to show in the Metric and just log the data as you like, refer to these [these samples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringPolicyExamples.html)

**Another Approach**

Based on your listed other approaches, maybe it's a worth a try looking for [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) , instead of creating a module that sends data with a snippet of code, In lambda, you will still have a chunk of code as a standalone application that you will setup on how it will be triggered depending on your setup either [cronjob style](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) or some aws services with [Cloudwatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html)

Comment: I don't want any dependency of AWS. I would prefer writing my own implementation for publishing metrics from applications.

Comment: There are couple of points to consider here 
1. How applications written in different languages will generate metrics?
2. How these metrics will be read by metric collector?
3. How metric collector will publish these metrics to the Kibana dashboard.

Comment: You have some suggestion?